# Copying info from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one sheet as long as the meet the twp below criteria. However, not all the data is being transferred. Any thing stand out to anyone as wrong in my code?

```
Private Sub FIlist()
Dim LastRow As Long, fgLastRow As Long
Dim c As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DaysReport").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = LastRow + 1

Call StartCode

With ActiveWorkbook

For c = 1 To LastRow

If .Sheets("DaysReport").Range("B1").Offset(c - 1, 0) = "ACCEPT" And .Sheets("DaysReport").Range("C1").Offset(c - 1, 0) = "ST" Then
    fgLastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FG LIST").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    fgLastRow = fgLastRow + 1
    .Sheets("FG LIST").Range("A" & fgLastRow) = .Sheets("DaysReport").Range("A2").Offset(c - 1, 0)
End If

    c = c + 1
Next c

End With

Call EndCode

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get rid of that

```
 c = c + 1
```

Which is making your loop variable update by steps of two !

Furthermore you may want to adopt the following refactoring of your code:

```
Private Sub FIlist()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim fgSht As Worksheet 

    Set fgSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FG LIST")

    StartCode

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DaysReport")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            If cell.Offset(,1).Value = "ACCEPT" And cell.Offset(,2).Value = "ST" Then fgSht.Cells(fgSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cell.Offset(1).Value
        Next
    End With

    EndCode
End Sub
```

Please note that I wrote:

```
            If cell.Offset(,1).Value = "ACCEPT" And cell.Offset(,2).Value = "ST" Then fgSht.Cells(fgSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cell.Offset(1).Value
```

To cope with your code that copied the value in column A one row below the current loop row

Should you actually need to copy the value in column A current row, then just remove that last  .Offset(1)

Comment: @musicalpoet, why did you remove the green checkmark?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out is that `c` should be `Long` as well.

The use of `ActiveWorkbook` may be a deliberate design choice - but if it always runs from this workbook, then use `ThisWorkbook`. Your user could change the workbook or active window at any time, thus causing chaos and mayhem (or at least unknown or undefined results).

Don't use `Call` - this is now deprecated. Not a show stopper, but still a bad habit.

Watch your index offsets, they can be confusing. Instead of `c-1` all the time, just set your start parameters earlier. This means that we remove a `+1` in a couple of spots as well!

Now that I tidied the code up - I saw the biggie. And the cause of your problems. I have left it commented in the code below. You are in a loop, and you also increment `c` (`c = c + 1`). This means that you skip every second row. If you really want to skip every second row then use `For c = 0 To LastRow Step 2` because it is clearer code and your intention is obvious.

```
Private Sub FIlist()
    Dim LastRow As Long, fgLastRow As Long
    Dim c As Integer
    StartCode
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DaysReport")
        LastRow = .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
        For c = 0 To LastRow
            If .Range("B1").Offset(c, 0) = "ACCEPT" And .Range("C1").Offset(c, 0) = "ST" Then
                fgLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FG LIST").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FG LIST").Range("A" & fgLastRow) = .Range("A2").Offset(c, 0)
            End If
            'c = c + 1
        Next c
    End With
    EndCode
End Sub
```